# WSO2DSS - REST POST operation call in JSON format : exception

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

Followed instructions in the below to send the json request payload in the curl command

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS351/JSON+Mapping+Sample.

Below is the curl command:

```
D:\testing\curl-7.46.0-win64\bin>curl -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data "@article-payload.json" http://8.39.51.27:9763/services/KMTool/insertarticles
```

The error:

```
**Error: Getting below error:**
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "article-payload.json", this makes an
Warning: empty POST.
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
<axis2ns22:DataServiceFault xmlns:axis2ns22="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"><ax
is2ns22:current_params>{articleTitle=null, articlePath=null, articleContent=null
, articleDesc=null, categoryID=null}</axis2ns22:current_params><axis2ns22:source
_data_service><axis2ns22:data_service_name>KMTool</axis2ns22:data_service_name><
axis2ns22:description>N/A</axis2ns22:description><axis2ns22:location>\KMTool.dbs
</axis2ns22:location><axis2ns22:default_namespace>http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
</axis2ns22:default_namespace></axis2ns22:source_data_service><axis2ns22:ds_code
>DATABASE_ERROR</axis2ns22:ds_code><axis2ns22:nested_exception>org.postgresql.ut
il.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "articleTitle" violates not-null c
onstraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (31, null, null, null, null, null).</axis2ns22:ne
sted_exception><axis2ns22:current_request_name>_postinsertarticles</axis2ns22:cu
rrent_request_name></axis2ns22:DataServiceFault>
```

I saved the file under below location:

```
C:\Users\testUser\Downloads\wso2dss-3.5.1\repository\deployment\server\dataservices\article-payload.json
```

Not sure what is causing issue. Just followed the instructions provided by wso2dss documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the parameters are not passed correctly (ex: articleTitle has become null, but in the database table you have defined it as a not null column). The article-payload.json file should be located in the directory that you are trying to invoke the request using curl (ie. inside D:\testing\curl-7.46.0-win64\bin)